# Como contar quantos caracteres maiúsculos existem em uma string?

Tags: c#

Como contar quantos caracteres maiúsculos existem em uma string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Há várias formas de fazer isso:

- **Usando LINQ:**

  ```
  var str = "Miguel Angelo";
  var contagem = str.Count(char.IsUpper);
  ```

  Nota: deve-se importar o namespace do LINQ: `using System.Linq;`
- **Sem usar LINQ:**

  ```
  var str = "Miguel Angelo";
  var contagem = 0;
  for (int itChar = 0; itChar < str.Length; itChar++)
      if (char.IsUpper(str[itChar]))
          contagem++;
  ```

### Performance

Fiz 4 testes de performance:

- `Sm str - LINQ`: teste com string de 13 chars usando LINQ
- `Sm str - FOR`: teste com string de 13 chars usando `for`
- `Lg str - LINQ`: teste com string de 13*1024 chars usando LINQ
- `Lg str - FOR`: teste com string de 13*1024 chars usando `for`

Resultados:

```
Exec #1
    Sm str - LINQ     1.092µs (84ns por char)
    Sm str - FOR      0.462µs (36ns por char)
    Lg str - LINQ   609.931µs (46ns por char)
    Lg str - FOR    425.092µs (32ns por char)
Exec #2
    Sm str - LINQ     1.013µs (78ns por char)
    Sm str - FOR      0.436µs (34ns por char)
    Lg str - LINQ   606.826µs (46ns por char)
    Lg str - FOR    433.585µs (33ns por char)
Exec #3
    Sm str - LINQ     1.017µs (78ns por char)
    Sm str - FOR      0.459µs (35ns por char)
    Lg str - LINQ   616.975µs (46ns por char)
    Lg str - FOR    443.754µs (33ns por char)
Exec #4
    Sm str - LINQ     1.086µs (84ns por char)
    Sm str - FOR      0.458µs (35ns por char)
    Lg str - LINQ   683.890µs (51ns por char)
    Lg str - FOR    441.979µs (33ns por char)
```

### Conclusão

Só dá para notar a diferença quando a string for maior que 100 milhões de caracteres. Seria um arquivo de ~100MB em utf-8.

Então: **Use a versão LINQ** em 99,99% dos casos.

Comment: Aprendi mais uma. LINQ só não faz chover!

Comment: Realmente é muito legal... mas nem sempre eficiente. Por isso dei duas opções: a legível e a rápida.

Comment: Um bom exemplo em que o LINQ é mais legível!

Comment: Editei e inclui testes de performance.

Comment: Julgo que na maioria das aplicações essas diferenças não são relevantes.

Comment: Não são relevantes mesmo. Só pra strings muito grandes mesmo. Como dá pra ver com uma string de 13KB, demora apenas 0.6ms, pra ser notável teria que ser uma string de 130MB, ai seriam 6s no LINQ e 4s no `for`... mas ainda assim é irrisório.

Comment: Tem uma dica de como/onde aprender/melhorar o conhecimento sobre LINQ? @MiguelAngelo

Comment: @HStackOverflow Eu aprendi tudo na internet e fazendo código. Tem muito material por ai, mas creio que a maior parte seja em inglês. LINQ na verdade é um conjunto do coisas que funcionam juntas para dar suporte àquela *sintaxe do linq*: métodos de extensão, interfaces `IEnumerable` e `IQueryable`, classes `EnumerableExtensions` e `QueryableExtensions`, inferência de parâmetros genéricos, expressões lambda e closures... deve ter mais alguns outros assuntos... pesquisa sobre essas coisas que vai entender mais sobre como o LINQ funciona.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode fazer isso usando expressão regular. 
Importe o namespace System.Text.RegularExpressions;

```
 var str = "Paulo Costa";
 var count = Regex.Matches(str, "[A-Z]").Count;
```